# Why this regex returns character instead of newline

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to insert something just before "test", I use this regex and expected that it would return newline but it returns "h" so if I insert with replace method I would not actually insert before "test" as I want : where's the mistake?

https://jsfiddle.net/y4qh629a/

```
  const test = `
  blah blah
  test blah blah`;

  const regex = /[^"]\s*(?=test)/;
  const match = test.match(regex);
  alert(match)
```

Comment: `[^"]` is the character `h`. `\s*` is the line break. Variable `match` contains the string `'h\n'`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that quote character? Can you provide some more inputs please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negated character class [^"] consumes a single character other than an `"` char, in this example that is the `h` char.

If you want to add something before the match, you can use replace instead or concat the value returned by match (note that [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array, and that `const test` can not be overwritten)

In this case, you can capture the full match using. In the replacement use the full match using `$&`.

Note that there should be at least a single character other than `"` present, which can also be a whitspace char.

```js
const test = `
  blah blah
  test blah blah`;


console.log(test.replace(/[^"]\s*(?=test)/, "$&[replacement]"));
```

If you also want to match `test` at the start of the string:

```js
const test = `test here
  blah blah
  test blah blah`;

console.log(test.replace(/(?:^|[^"])\s*(?=test)/g, "$&[replacement]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind instead:

#### `(?!<=")\s*(?=test)`

```js
const test = `
      blah blah
      test blah blah`;

const regex = /(?!<=")\s*(?=test)/;
const match = test.match(regex);
console.log(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[^"]` matches a single character.

Maybe you want to match unlimited times?  Just add `+` a.e. `[^"]+`

```
const regex = /[^"]+\s*(?=test)/;
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLotb30x/)</kbd>